DLL switch over issue while AOAG automatic failover
We have configured AOAG in our environment, but when performing automatic failover from one node to another, the DLL is not enabled automatically in the second node. We are manually enabling the DLL again in the node where the failover happened.
Can anyone let us know the process for automating the DLL enabling without manual intervention?

What does DLL mean, in this context?

Hi Tibor, I should have talked a bit about the DLL. My bad! In the DATABASE, we have certain static functions that are linked as ASSEMBLIES.

(Cont.) Now, this assembly references a DLL (again in the DATABASE, which we see in the Sql server mgmt studio) from a specific location on the DB server. This DLL (Dynamic Linked Library) is created from an application and generated as a DLL.   In primary, when we copy this DLL in a particular location, and manually reference this to the ASSEMBLY, things are fine.

(Cont.) When the FAILOVER happens, though the ASSEMBLY is seen in the secondary, the DLL is not copied to a similar folder when AOAG is set up.   We also tried to manually create the FOLDER and copy the DLL in the location of the secondary before setting up the AOAG, but it did not work.  Only if we manually link the assembly to the DLL again, it works.  But that means manual intervention is required during FAIL OVER, which is the problem.

This Q&A might help.

@ST Clarifications should be part of the original question, not in the comment threads.


We also tried to manually create the FOLDER and copy the DLL in the location of the secondary before setting up the AOAG, but it did not work.

You'll just need to troubleshoot your setup process.  This is the correct approach.
